# Is Gyroscopic precession relative to the object in precessions axis of movement when there is drag imposed on the disc?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, aircraft, gyroscopes, precession

Does my question make sense? I am referring to the disc of an [AutoGyro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autogyro) aircraft. Though the fuselage of a modern pusher AutoGyro will weather vane into the wind, the disc that provides lift does not. Is this because the gyroscopic force acting on the disc is greater than the winds force to change its movement?  Although I am learning to fly an AutoGyro I still dont understand what is going on while above happens, trying to understand it to better my understanding of the physics involved.

Answer (score 0):

Precession is the result of any angular momentum differential of the tangental velocity.

$$ L = m \cdot v \times r $$

Such that $  P = m\frac{dv}{dt} \times r $ or $ P = m \cdot v \times \frac{dr}{dt} $

Both of these a facet of torque without a kick.

The differentials could be imposed by a multitude of phenomenon, from a friction, an external force or geometric implications.